# How to print a message when action is succeeded?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I am currently developing an application which grades scores. When the method I wrote runs successfully, I want to notify the user that the action is successful. However, when I try to achieve this by placing the method inside a try/catch/finally block, the finally block is hit regardless if the method ran successful.

The success message is a variable string, so that's why it isn't in "" in the finally block.

I have the following catch/finally code:

```
  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Success);
            }
```

So when the method returns an error, the user will still get the message that the action is succeeded. How can I solve this?

thanks.

Comment: `finally block is hit regardless if the method ran successful` this is true. I recommend reading the [try-finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) documents to get an understanding of how this works. IMHO you don't need the `finally` block.

Comment: I know how the finally block works, i was wondering how i can solve this any other way?

Comment: There's multiple ways to solve it, removing the `finally` block, you don't need it, write to a variable and then use that to show what you need etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the finally block is hit regardless if the method ran successful.

Yes, that's how a `finally` block works.

Move `MessageBox.Show(Success)` to the last line of the `try` block and remove the `finally` block:

```
try
{
    //do something that might throw....

    MessageBox.Show(Success);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Then `MessageBox.Show(Success)` will only be called when there is no exception thrown.

Comment: When i do this, it still runs the success message when it hits an exception

Comment: No, it doesn't if you remove the `finally` block. A method cannot both return *and* throw an exception.

Comment: i'm sorry i placed it between the wrong {}. it works, thanks for your help!